How to build an isomorphic API client with dynamic headers in next js?
I have a next js application with a separate API. All API endpoints require a specific X-HOST request header. I want to prefetch requests on the server side and sometimes invalidate them on the client side. I use axios and @tanstack/react-query. I need to get the host from the context.req inside the getServerSideProps on the server and from the window.location.host on the client. The issue here is that I need to create a new axios instance inside the getServerSideProps to avoid data leaks between different users, and set the X-HOST header inside a request interceptor. At the same time, I want to use the same API functions e.g. getUsers for the client-side and server-side using the react-query. What are the best practices to create this kind of application?
My simplified implementation looks like this:
const createFetchClient = () => axios.create();

const createQueryClient = (fetchClient: AxiosInstance) => new QueryClient({
  queries: {
    meta: {
      fetchClient
    },
  },
})

const getUsers = async (params) => {
  const { fetchClient } = params;
  const { data } = fetchClient.get('/users');
  return data;
}

// queryOptions from react-query
const usersQuery = queryOptions({
  queryKey: ['users'],
  queryFn: ({ meta }) => getUsers({ fetchClient: meta!.fetchClient }),
})

Server-side:


export const getServerSideProps = async (context) => {
  const fetchClient = createFetchClient();
  fetchClient.interceptors.request.use((config) => {
    config.headers['x-host'] = context.req.headers.host;
    return config;
  });

  const queryClient = createQueryClient(fetchClient);
  
  await queryClient.prefetchQuery(usersQuery);
  
  // The meta is included to the dehydrated state. 
  // We remove the fetchClient by using this workaround
  return { props: { dehydratedState: JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(dehydrate(queryClient))) } }
}

Client-side:
const Providers = ({ children }) => {
  const [queryClient] = useState(() => createQueryClient(createFetchClient()));

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchClient = queryClient.getDefaultOptions().queries?.meta?.fetchClient;

    if (!fetchClient) return;

    const interceptor = fetchClient.interceptors.request.use((config) => {
      config.headers['x-host'] = window.location.host;
      return config;
    });

    return () => {
      fetchClient.interceptors.request.eject(interceptor);
    }

  }, [queryClient]);
  
  return <QueryClientProvider client={queryClient}>{children}</QueryClientProvider>
}

const MyComponent = () => {
  const users = useQuery(usersQuery);
  ...
}

I would like to get rid of passing fetchClient in the meta somehow, but at the same time, I don't want to pass host to each API function.
